# PMD errors unable to resolve in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, exception, pmd

I have created a below java service in eclipse and reviewed the code using PMD plugin I'm getting below errors

** Errors **

```
DataflowAnomalyAnalysis: Found 'DD'-anomaly for variable 'result' (lines '80'-'83').
SignatureDeclareThrowsException: A method/constructor should not explicitly throw java.lang.Exception
```

**java service**

```
@GetMapping("OCR/GetBarcodeRead")
    @ApiOperation("Get result from Barcode Zxing library")
    public String getBarcodeRead() throws Exception {

        String result = new String();

        try {
            result = service.zxing();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            result = "";

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Could someone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Get rid of `= new String()`, it is unnecessary. Besides, you should never have need to call that particular constructor. --- 2) Remove `throws Exception`, since you code doesn't actually throw one of those.

Comment: You can find explanations about it in the PMD's reference. For example https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_errorprone.html#dataflowanomalyanalysis and https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_design.html#signaturedeclarethrowsexception. If you look for suggestions to solve this warning  I recommend the sonarlint plugin https://www.sonarlint.org/ that offers compliant solutions to these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaring you throwing `Exception`, but you aren't, so remove it

```
public String getBarcodeRead() {
```

Also remove `new String()` and initialize it with `""`

```
String result = "";
```

Comment: There is no initialization required here, so it should be `String result;`, not `String result = "";` (or even better, return the value directly without storing it in a variable).

Comment: @howlger if you want 1 return statement I think it's better to remove assignment `result = "";`

Comment: Nobody wants code that is harder to read and less performant.

Comment: @howlger IMHO initialize result variable with default value isn't that harder to read

Comment: In Java it is bad style, not a matter of taste. People do such obfuscating because they are used to it from other programming languages or because they have learned it from others. Removing the line `result = "";` makes it even worse. Think what happens if you add the line `result += service.zxingSuffix();` at the end of the _try_ block.